# Automating the drag and drop functionality in protractor

Tags: automation, protractor

I am writing a test to interchange columns using drag and drop.Can anybody help me to automate it using protractor....

Answer (score 0):

I have a different implementation from the answer given at the thread to which @wap300 is pointing to.
Use -
`elementToDrag.click();
browser.actions().dragAndDrop(elementToDrag, locationToDragTo))).perform();`

Comment: Why not just answer that question then?

Comment: Used this code didnt get any errors but its not working

Comment: @Martjin Thanx. Will post it there also. But seems like it is not working..:(